# Dagger Component Getting From Application Class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am new to the dagger in android, I need to get the object directly from the component, But i need to know is this the proper way of doing.
Example
The class i need to inject using dagger

```
@Singleton
class Testing @Inject constructor(){

}
```

```
@Singleton
@Component(...)
interface AppComponent {
    ...

@Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: MyApplication): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun getTest(): Testing

    fun inject(application: MyApplication)
}
```

```
class Myapplication : Application(){

    lateinit var appComponent : AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        initializeDagger()
    }

    private void initializeDagger() {
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .build();
        appComponent.inject(this);

    }
}
```

For getting the injected class i.e `Testing`

```
class Tester {

 fun getTesting() : Testing{
   return applicationContext.appComponent.getTest()
 }
}
```

I need to the know this is the right way of doing or any other alternative solution is available?
can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using `getTest()` you can use `@Inject lateinit var test: Testing`. Also, you need to create another `inject()` function that receives your class and use `DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this)` in your class. Dagger will automatically inject it for you.

For more info, check [this page](https://medium.com/@elye.project/dagger-2-for-dummies-in-kotlin-with-one-page-simple-code-project-618a5f9f2fe8). It has the basic stuff of Dagger.

Anyway, Dagger 2 also has another way to implement that you don't even need to have `inject()` inside your class.

Edit: Here is my code about simple Dagger

```
class Info @Inject constructor(){
    val text = "Dagger2"
}

@Component()
interface InfoComponent {
    fun inject(app: MainActivity)
    fun inject(box: Box)
}

class Box {
    @Inject
    lateinit var info: Info

    init {
        DaggerInfoComponent.create().inject(this)
    }

    fun getInfo(): String {
        return info.text
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val box = Box()
        hello_text.text = box.getInfo()
    }
}
```

You can also search more about AndroidInjector, with it you don't need to explicitly insert `inject()` function to every classes you need injection

Comment: In your code you can inject the `Testing` object directly into where you need it. I think you don't have to create a getter method `getTesting()` from class `Tester`.

Comment: is it possible to inject the ```Testing``` without making the class the Injectable i.e i will create the Tester object manually, But i need the Testing to be injected by dagger.

Comment: Do you want to inject into a POJO class? You can't use `inject(class)` inside it?

Comment: what i mean is Example. ```Tester().getTesting()``` But in the Tester class i will inject the  Testing class using ```@Inject``` is it possible ?

Comment: I will edit my answer. You should check it if it is what you need